# Generating $n$ $2$-D points, of which the correlation coefficient is $r$

Tags: statistics, correlation

I am just wondering this question: given any correlation coefficient $r$, generate a set of $n$ points that fits this correlation coefficient. Is there any efficient existing algorithm to achieve the goal?